# Vue.js Returns JSON when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I am new to vue.js , and I am loving it already, except for the fact that I am stocked with an ugly part I don't like which is "page returns JSON when I hit on refresh"

[image: page loads normaly]
[image: On Refresh Page loads JSON]

However if I go through the master page, i.e the main page it loads correctly as expected, but if I click on refresh I get a JSON response.

I am using laravel for my backend, in my controller, I am returning a JSON Response (yes I know), however, I am kind of expecting vue.js to auto-detect links for me and do its magic like it would if I go to the link/page from the master page.

Here is what the controller returning the item to the master page looks like

```
public function index()
{
    //
        $task = TodoTask::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4);
        return \request()->json(200, $task);

}
```

I have done quite a couple of research on this, and I got to understand from this link 
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations that I have got to configure my .htaccess file to be able to do so.

Here is what my .htaccess file looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What might I possibly be doing wrong?

my vue routes

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

window.Vue.use(VueRouter);

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
//Vue.component('tasks', require('./components/TodoTask.vue'));
const example = require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue');
const Samplelink = require('./components/SampleComponent.vue');
const task = require('./components/TodoTask.vue');



const routes = [{
    path: '/example',
    component: example

}, {
    path: '/sample',
    component: Samplelink
}, {
    path: '/tasks',
    component: task
}];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: Can you show me your routes? Are you using Vue Router?

Comment: actually the problem is that. you manage your route in both sides. from vue and laravel. so when you refresh the page. the laravel consider you are calling laravel route and it gives you response. i am sharing my repo which covers it all, its a youtube clone app in vue and laravel, see how the routes are declare in both sides. 

https://github.com/musman92/laravel-vue-app

Comment: Hello -  thanks for sharing your projext, i just finished viewing it, i discovered that your link structure is quite diffrent from mine, or what i have in mind, i want to totally eliminate all pound sign in the url.

Comment: Example - http://blog.test/#/tasks or http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/account it looks to weird.